# Rad Studio 10.2.3 error when install apk: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, rad-studio

How can I solve this problem?

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb install Project.apk
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install Project.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed collecting certificates for /data/app/vmdl1331479076.tmp/base.apk: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl1331479076.tmp/base.apk: Attempt to get length of null array]
```

I am using RAD STUDIO 10.2.3, with SDK 25 to compile an app on Android 11.
Thank you!

Comment: Hi, have you configured the signature for your app? 
See https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing 
You can also use a debug certificate.